# datetime varchar yyyymmdd_hhmiss to datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have `datetime` format in `varchar` `yyyymmdd_hhmiss` format. I need to convert it to SQL Server datetime .

Is there any easier way ?

for example, `20150622_012030` into `'2015-06-22 01:20:30.000'` datetime

I got my code below but not sure how to convert time part

```
      SELECT CONVERT(DATEtime,LEFT('20150617_015814',8)), RIGHT('20150617_015814',6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Change the format to yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss then do the convert
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
    STUFF(
    STUFF(
        REPLACE('20150622_012030', '_', ' ')
    , 14, 0, ':')
    , 12, 0, ':')
)

-- Result
2015-06-22 01:20:30.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @datetime varchar(6) = right('20150622_012030',6)
declare @date varchar(10) = left('20150622_012030',8)
SELECT convert(datetime,@date+' '+left(@datetime,2)+':'+RIGHT(left(@datetime,4),2)+':'+RIGHT(@datetime,2))
```